# Text To Speech problems

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I want to do a text to speech test application, seeing this tutorial: http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html

I tryed doing what the tutorial says, and i'm setting the language only to spanish:

```
mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
   Locale loc = new Locale ("spa", "ESP");
   mTts.setLanguage(loc);
```

Also i tryed doing this (not works):

```
// Specify the exact voice you are checking for
checkIntent.putExtra(TextToSpeech.Engine.EXTRA_CHECK_VOICE_DATA_FOR,"spa-ESP");
```

The problem is that when the app starts, the app prompts me to a screen asking me download four languages, GERMAN, SPANISH, FRENCH, ITALIAN. If i only download spanish language and then i press back key, the app works, but EACH TIME i start the app, it shows me the same screen to download the other three languages, and only stop appearing if i download the foru languages.

My objective is to prompt the user to download ONLY spanish, and to show the languages download dialog only one time, not allways.

I'm testing it on a Nexus S phone with 4.1

This is the full code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnInitListener {  
    private static final int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;
    EditText editText;
    Button button;
    private TextToSpeech mTts;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);    

    editText.setText("Estoy probando, porque hay que probar.");                 

    Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
    checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
    startActivityForResult(checkIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mTts.speak(editText.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);              
        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
            // success, create the TTS instance
            mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
            Locale loc = new Locale ("spa", "ESP");
            mTts.setLanguage(loc);
        } else {
            // missing data, install it
            Intent installIntent = new Intent();
            installIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            startActivity(installIntent);

            mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
            Locale loc = new Locale ("spa", "ESP");
            mTts.setLanguage(loc);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onInit(int arg0) {}
}
```

I hope you will help me to find a solution

Greetings

Comment: check 'always use my settings' under the text to speech settings.

Answer (score 1):

You must not use [MARC codes](http://www.loc.gov/marc/languages/language_code.html) but     [ISO-639-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-1) / [ISO-3166-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1) codes to create a locale: `Locale loc = new Locale ("es");`. Also see the "Class Overview" section in the [Locale class reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html).